# is there any better way to read and append files in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Basically, I am working on a project where I am making a Hotel Management System in Bash Script. All is working fine, but i am having problem in appending data to files and then reading (printing) them. There are total 5 files each for a separate hotel. The issue is that no matter what i do, the data gets saved in only the same first file and the same file is printed no matter which file is called.
**I Have separated the filing code so, it will be easier to focus on the main issue**.

```
filesave(){
$name, $totalp, $id, $hnum;
#Input Details
echo "Enter your name: "
read name
echo "Enter the total number of people: "
read totalp
#Assigning Random ID
id=$RANDOM

#Selecting file
echo "Enter hotel number"
read hnum
if [[ hnum=="1" ]]; then
echo "Customer ID: $id " >> Ramada.txt
echo "Customer Name: $name " >> Ramada.txt
echo "Total Number of People: $totalp " >> Ramada.txt
echo
#
elif [[ hnum=="2" ]]; then
echo "Customer ID: $id " >> Tm.txt
echo "Customer Name: $name " >> Tm.txt
echo "Total Number of People: $totalp " >> Tm.txt
echo
#
elif [[ hnum=="3" ]]; then
echo "Customer ID: $id " >> Mehran.txt
echo "Customer Name: $name " >> Mehran.txt
echo "Total Number of People: $totalp " >> Mehran.txt
echo
#
elif [[ hnum=="4" ]]; then
echo "Customer ID: $id " >> Mp.txt
echo "Customer Name: $name " >> Mp.txt
echo "Total Number of People: $totalp " >> Mp.txt
echo
#
elif [[ hnum=="5" ]]; then
echo "Customer ID: $id " >> PC.txt
echo "Customer Name: $name " >> PC.txt
echo "Total Number of People: $totalp " >> PC.txt
echo
fi
echo "ROOM SUCCESSFULLY BOOKED!!! "
echo "Enjoy your stay"
}

showdata(){
$selecth;
echo "Enter Hotel Number: "
read selecth
if [[ selecth=="1" ]]; then
clear
echo "Processing request..."
echo "Hotel: Ramada"
cat Ramada.txt
#
#
elif [[ selecth=="2" ]]; then
clear
echo "Processing request..."
echo "Hotel: Taj Mahal"
cat Tm.txt
# 
#
elif [[ selecth=="3" ]]; then
clear
echo "Processing request..."
echo "Hotel: MEHRAN"
cat Mehran.txt
#
#
elif [[ selecth=="4" ]]; then
clear
echo "Processing request..."
echo "Hotel: Move and Pick"
cat Mp.txt
#
#
elif [[ selecth=="5" ]]; then
clear
echo "Processing request..."
echo "Hotel: Pearl Continental"
cat PC.txt
#
#
fi
}

#Main
filesave
echo "Now u can view your data by entering the hotel number"
showdata
```

Anyone please help me out. I think maybe i am making mistakes in not correctly appending or reading a file, but i have searched for everything now but i don't even know where the error is even.

Comment: This might help: [CASE Statement in Bash](https://www.shellhacks.com/case-statement-bash-example/)

Comment: You could define an array with hotels `hotels=("" "Ramada" "Tm" "Mehran" "Mp" "PC")` (empty string is there for padding as your `hnum` is one based and you can expand the name from the array based on `hnum` being your index: `echo "Some output"  >> "${hotels[$hnum]}"`.

Comment: @OndrejK. ok, i'll check it out.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this code. `[[ hnum=="4" ]]` is *always true*, no matter what value is in a variable named `hnum`, or even whether or not such a variable exists at all. A good place to start is running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and addressing what it finds.

Comment: Beyond that, this question isn't addressing a single, specific problem -- as our rules require. See the [mre] page in the Help Center; an ideal question contains the *shortest possible code* that reproduces a single, specific problem; with everything not needed to demonstrate and test for that problem removed.

Comment: Are the lines like `$name, $totalp, $id, $hnum;` intended to declare function-local variables, or something like that? If so, that's not the right syntax at all. You need to use the `local` command, and don't use dollar-sign (that *gets* the value of a variable) or comma (and you don't need the semicolon at the end of the line either). So it'd be something like: `local name totalp id hnum`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing your `if` statement (which can be replaced with a `case` statement) needs to do is set a variable to the name of the file to append to. (And the name of the hotel in `showdata`.)

```
filesave() {
  #Input Details
  echo "Enter your name: "
  read name
  echo "Enter the total number of people: "
  read totalp
  #Assigning Random ID
  id=$RANDOM

  #Selecting file
  echo "Enter hotel number"
  read hnum

  case $hnum in
    1) fname=Ramada.txt ;;
    2) fname=Tm.txt ;;
    3) fname=Mehran.txt ;;
    4) fname=Mp.txt ;;
    5) fname=PC.txt ;;
    *) echo "Invalid choice: $hnum" >&2; return 1 ;;
  esac

  printf '%s: %s\n' \
    "Customer ID" "$id" \
    "Customer Name" "$name" \
    "Total Number of People" "$totalp" \
    >> "$fname"
 
  echo "ROOM SUCCESSFULLY BOOKED!!! "
  echo "Enjoy your stay"
}

showdata(){
  echo "Enter Hotel Number: "
  read selecth

  
  case $selecth in
    1) hotel=Ramada; fname=Ramada.txt ;;
    2) hotel="Taj Mahal"; fname=Tm.txt ;;
    3) hotel=MEHRAN; fname=Mehran.txt ;;
    4) hotel="Move and Pick"; fname=Mp.txt ;;
    5) hotel="Pearl Continental"; fname=PC.txt ;;
    *) echo "Invalid choice: $selecth" >&2; return 1 ;;
  esac

  clear
  printf 'Processing request...\nHotel: %s\n' "$hotel"
  cat "$fname"
}

#Main
filesave
echo "Now u can view your data by entering the hotel number"
showdata
```

Comment: why haven't you enclosed Ramada and MEHRAN in inverted commas in showdata method?

Comment: They don't need to be; you can add them for consistency, but their purpose in the other three is to escape the space that would otherwise terminate the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of the filenames and an array of the names.

Here is an example.  Make sure that your script is run using `bash` rather than `sh`, for arrays to be supported.

Note that the code subtracts 1 when indexing the array, because array indexes start from zero in bash (in common with many other languages), but the hotel numbers start from 1.

Incidentally, I have added `-n` on the `echo` statements to suppress newlines, so that you type the response on the same line as the prompt.

In the error checking, I have used `exit 1` if you put in an invalid choice (the script will terminate).  Alternatively you could have `return 1` and the function will return with status 1 (indicating an error) but the script will continue.

```
#!/bin/bash

files=(Ramada.txt Tm.txt Mehran.txt Mp.txt PC.txt)
names=(Ramada "Taj Mahal" MEHRAN "Move and Pick" "Pearl Continental")

filesave(){
    #Input Details
    echo -n "Enter your name: "
    read name
    echo -n "Enter the total number of people: "
    read totalp
    #Assigning Random ID
    id=$RANDOM
    
    #Selecting file
    echo -n "Enter hotel number: "
    read hnum
    
    filename=${files[$hnum-1]}
    if [ -z "$filename" ]
    then
        echo "Hotel number not recognised" >&2
        exit 1
    fi

    echo "Customer ID: $id " >> $filename
    echo "Customer Name: $name "  >> $filename
    echo "Total Number of People: $totalp "  >> $filename
    
    echo "ROOM SUCCESSFULLY BOOKED!!! "
    echo "Enjoy your stay"
}

showdata(){
    echo -n "Enter Hotel Number: "
    read selecth

    hotel_name=${names[$selecth-1]}
    filename=${files[$selecth-1]}
    if [ -z "$filename" ]
    then
        echo "Hotel number not recognised" >&2
        exit 1
    fi

    clear
    echo "Processing request..."
    echo "Hotel: $hotel_name"
    cat $filename
}

#Main
filesave
echo "Now u can view your data by entering the hotel number"
showdata
```